# Calling an image inside resources in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm new in Laravel and I want to put an image but when I tried this, I got a 404 error:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
<img src="{{ asset('img/logo.jpg') }}" width="50" height="50" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
</a>
```

```
src="{{ asset('img/logo.jpg') }}
The image is inside resources/img
```

But I still got a 404 error, file not found, I don´t know how to show the image. I'm using Laravel 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `resources` in the browser. Put your images in `public` somewhere. User-uploaded stuff goes in `storage/app/public`, which should be linked to the public directory via `php artisan storage:link`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-public-disk